# Sure Google Appengine scales, but is it also fast?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to know if responsetimes are good, not just if it scales. Anyone with experiences?

Answer (score 5):

A scalable architecture like GAE is not the same as one based on optimizing speed. A different approach is needed.

The DataStore isn't designed to be super fast at the small scale, but rather handle large amounts of data, and be distributed.  We could say that database access is "very slow" at the small scale (compared with a standard relational database).

Take a look at: [google-appengine-second-look](http://highscalability.com/google-appengine-second-look) and [how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-love-using-lot-disk-space-scale](http://highscalability.com/how-i-learned-stop-worrying-and-love-using-lot-disk-space-scale)

Some [experimental results](http://www.ongwt.com/post/2008/05/24/Google-App-Engine-1-Community-0).

Comment: To clarify the above points, the GAE datastore has been optimized first for scalability and after that for reads.  Writes are slow, but it turns out that queries and gets are pretty fast, in practical terms.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented some ajax popups for a GAE application and the popups need a server round trip to be less than half second on average to be usable. And it turned out to work pretty well. The support for memcache also makes it easy to optimize for speed on GAE.

Answer (score 2):

the existing answers (and comment) are on the right track. a succinct summary would be, the app engine datastore is slower than most relational databases but faster than most other NoSQL-style datastores. i've seen a few independent  comparisons reflect this, e.g. http://radar.oreilly.com/2010/06/on-the-performance-of-clouds.html

app engine has tracked the datastore's latency for years on its system status site: http://code.google.com/status/appengine